# Basic Typelist functionality

Tags: c++, typelist

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around TypeLists or lists of templates.  That is:

```
class nulltype{};

template <typename HEAD, typename TAIL>
struct tlist
{
    typedef HEAD head;
    typedef TAIL tail;
}; 

template <class TList>
class OutputClass
{
public:
    void output(Type t) 
    {
        std::cout << t << endl;
    }
};

typedef tlist<double,tlist<float,NullType> > floatingPoints;    
typedef tlist<std::string,tlist<char *,NullType> > text;   

int main()
{
    OutputClass<floatingPoints> floats = OutputClass<floatingPoints>();
    floats.output(1.0f);

    OutputClass<text> strings = OutputClass<text>();
    floats.output("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Basically my goal is that I would like OutputClass.output to output the parameter passed to it, but only if that class instances typelist contains the type passed into the function.  ie. referring to the above code: floats can only output float type and double type as defined by its typelist, "floatingPoints".  Should a string or int get passed in, I would hope it would error.

I'm having one hell of a time trying to find any examples on how to do this, I've found the indexing examples and length examples a million times over, and they have helped me a lot, but i just can't seem to figure this last bit out.  Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, nevermind my answer, I misread the question completely.

Comment: No problems, thanks for stopping by and having a crack anyway :) very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first need some helper templates. The first one checks if two types are the same:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    // Default case: T and U are not the same type
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
    // Specialization: both template arguments are of the same type
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

We can now use the boolean `is_same<T, U>::value` to determine if the types `T` and `U` are equivalent.

Using `is_same` we can now write a template which checks if a specific type occurs in a type list:

```
template <typename TList, typename T>
struct contains
{
    static const bool value =
         is_same<typename TList::head, T>::value   // Base case
      || contains<typename TList::tail, T>::value; // Recursion
};

template <typename T>
struct contains<nulltype, T>
{
    // Termination condition
    static const bool value = false;
};
```

This is a recursive template, using a specialization on `nulltype` to terminate the recursion.

One final helper template we need is `enable_if`:

```
template <bool Cond, typename T=void>
struct enable_if
{
    // Default case: Cond assumed to be false, no typedef
};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{
    // Specialization: Cond is true, so typedef
    typedef T type;
};
```

`enable_if<true, T>::type` yields `T`, whereas `enable_if<false, T>::type` is undefined. We exploit the [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) rule the enable or disable a function depending on its template argument, like so:

```
template <typename TList>
class OutputClass
{
public:
    // Only enable the function if T is in TList (by SFINAE)
    template <typename T>
    typename enable_if<contains<TList, T>::value>::type
    output(T t) 
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Quite a trip, but if you understand all of this you're well on your way to master template metaprogramming. For an in-depth discussion of template metaprogramming I recommend you pick up a copy of [C++ Template Metaprogramming](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Abrahams-C-Template-Metaprogramming-Concepts-Tools-and-Techniques-from-Boost-and-Beyond/PGM93893.html) (ISBN-13: 9780321227256).

Comment: worked like a charm. I find these type lists really fascinating, I   will definitely have to check out that book. Thanks again! You've really helped me understand type lists much better now

Comment: If the standard form for a function template is `template <typename T> [return type] [name]([arguments])`, then does that mean that the return type of `OutputClass::output()` is the result of instantiating the template `typename enable_if<contains<TList, T>::value>::type` ?

Comment: @Chris `enable_if<contains<TList, T>::value>::type` is technically not a template, it is a `typedef` which happens to be defined in a template. But yes, it is the return type of `OutputClass<TList>::output<T>()`. Did that answer your question?

Comment: the link to the book is dead as of 2016.04.18

Comment: @ofloveandhate Thanks, I updated the link and added the ISBN for future reference.