# How to create object using enum element

Tags: c++, enums

My enum consists of Class names. Ex:

```
class A{};
class B{};

class example{
    enum set_of_classnames {A,B}

};
```

I want to create objects of classes `A` and `B` in the example class. Using iterator or `for` loop can I create objects for A and B by taking enum element?

Comment: Perhaps a `std::map` mapping the enumerations to factory functions?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're asking and very broad the range of possible solutions to your problem

Comment: Oh, and instead of asking us to help with a solution to an unknown problem, why don't you tell us what problem you are actually trying to solve with this solution? Please see [this related reading](http://xyproblem.info/) about the XY problem.

Comment: You could make a typelist and enumerate over that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704589/basic-typelist-functionality) but (trying to) putting types in an enum instead of numbers won't work.

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have common base class ? is the enum value knows at compile time ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
set_of_classnames choice = choose(); // class can be chosen at runtime
if(choice == A) {
    class A object;
} else if(choice == B) {
    class B object;
}
```

This code can be used in a loop.